# Подскажите как обратиться к #document, внутри iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Делаю автопроход гуглокапчи и закончив с логической частью столкнулся с тупой проблемой, не могу обратиться к элементу вложенного документа в iframe.

Пытаюсь обратиться к внутренностям iframe таким образом:

```
const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
console.log("iframe:", iframe.contentWindow)
```

И получаю:

[image]

Насколько я понял, я не могу ничего изменять из за политики безопасности, но конкретно с кликами по элементам у меня проблем быть не должно. Как решить проблему?

[Сайт на котором я провожу тесты](https://captcha.guru/ru/feedback)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, вы работаете из дополнения. Добавьте нужные вам сайты в `manifest.json`. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/externally_connectable/

```
 "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "*://captcha.guru/*"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, использую расширение tampermonkey, прописал в настройках скрипта пользовательский матч и смог обратиться к документу, но теперь выходит так, что документ имеет разметку html, с пустым header и body.

Comment: Вы после события [onload](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded) обращаетесь?

Comment: Нет, я обращаюсь по 2х секундному таймауту для теста. Сейчас уже попробовал обратиться без contentWindow и каким то образом получалось 3 вызова фрейма, из которых верным был только первый. Сделал проверку, что появился нужный и записал в переменную, но теперь опять не могу обратиться к документу через contentWindow из за cors ошибки. Видимо еще какой то домен нужно разрешить, пока поразбираюсь.

Comment: В общем у меня так и не получилось получить доступ, если у вас есть время, может тоже попробуете?

Comment: Могу посоветовать не использовать `tampermonkey` а написать своё дополнение к браузеру, там свободы побольше.